# Background shell script can't reach directories after ssh logout, even with nohup

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to run a shell script in the background on a server machine and starts that shell script from an ssh connection. Even though I run the background process script with `nohup`, **the background script fails due to an *directory unreachable* error as soon as I close my ssh connection** (and no sooner).

**runInBackground.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
nohup ./run.sh > /dev/null 2> local/errorLog.txt < /dev/null &
```

**run.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
while [ true ] ; do
    ...
    cd optaplanner-examples
    mvn exec:exec // calls java process
    cd ..
done
```

So when I run `runInBackground.sh`, everything works fine for hours, until I disconnect my ssh connection.
As soon as I log out, the `errorlog.txt` fills up with:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/myUser/server/optaplanner-simple-benchmark-daemon/local/output/
./run.sh: line 64: /home/myUser/server/optaplanner-simple-benchmark-daemon/local/processed/failed_machineReassignmentBenchmarkConfig.xml: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not change back to '(unreachable)/server/optaplanner-simple-benchmark-daemon/local/optaplannerGitClone/optaplanner': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /home/myUser/server/optaplanner-simple-benchmark-daemon/local/input: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /home/myUser/server/optaplanner-simple-benchmark-daemon/local/input: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /home/myUser/server/optaplanner-simple-benchmark-daemon/local/input: No such file or directory
... // 1000+ more of that ls error
```

([Full source code](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner-simple-benchmark-daemon))

Comment: Probably unrelated to the problem but you shouldn't be [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) at all. Use a glob instead.

Comment: What OS is this system running? Are you using systemd? Could this be systemd cleaning up your session and using a "temporary" set of directories or something?

Comment: The OS on my old server is Ubuntu (although I ssh from Fedora). In any case, I want this shell script to work on any linux.

Comment: Interesting thing to check if the user dir is encrypted. It's an old computer, but I remember potentially enabling user directory encryption. Is there a command to test if the user directory is encrypted?

Comment: [How to tell if user directory is encrypted](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53242/check-if-partition-is-encrypted)

Comment: Also unrelated, but from the context, you should change `[ true ]` to `true`. This is because `[ any_random_text ]` will always result to be `true`, so `[ false ]` is also `true`, creating confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well, it's not necessarily an *encrypted* home directory, but likely it's an auto-mounted home directory (e.g over NFS or so). It's mounted upon session startup, and unmounted upon exit. An encrypted home dir is only one of the possible reasons to use such a technique.

The main question is what's the rule that determines whether a user needs home dir or not. I would expect that it could be an allocated [pty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal). You could test if it's actually true by starting a non-interactive SSH session w/o a pseudo-terminal: `ssh -T user@host ls /home/myUser/server`. I could expect that in this case you won't get a proper directory listing.

Then I would use a program like [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) to prolongate interactive session lifetime beyond SSH session limits.

The server might use some other mechanism to provide the home directory for interactive SSH sessions. E.g. monitor interactive sessions listed in [utmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp) In this case you will need a program that would keep the record as long as you need for your service. Perhaps you could use an automatically re-established SSH session. For example I use the following systemd unit to automatically keep a ssh tunnel from one of my workstations in different private networks:

```
[Unit]
Description=A tunnel to SOME_HOST
PartOf=sshd.service
Requires=network.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -N -q -R 2222:localhost:22 SOME_HOST
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
User=tunnel
Group=tunnel

[Install]
WantedBy=sshd.service
WantedBy=network.service
```

When a failure occurs, systemd automatically restarts the unit and SSH session is re-established.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the **screen** utility to run my scripts instead of nohup.

With *screen* your process will keep running in even your current ssh session times out or gets disconnected.

Use as follows -

```
apt-get install screen (On Debian based Systems)
```

OR

```
yum install screen (On RedHat based Systems)
```

To run your application and check the output live (provided your script file does not start a background process and it outputs to the stdout and/or stderr

```
cd your_app_directory_path
screen ./your_script.sh
```

Once you are done and want to leave (without stopping the process), use **CTRL + A + D** to detach the screen.

To check your processes which are run using the screen utility -

```
screen -r
```

to reattach a running process

```
screen -r <screen id or name>
```

Hope this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use `screen` to keep the ssh session open. You can use `screen -r` to reconnect to the session if you get disconnected.